# Shoes4 Excel File Content Upload

Tags: ruby, jruby, shoes

I want to upload the content of excel and csv file.

I was trying with the helper of "ask_save_file", it was reading the uploaded file path say example "/Desktop/file_name" as "string" but I want to read the content of that file, how can I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**`roo gem`**](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo)

Here is reference link to start with this gem.

- [RubyDoc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/roo/1.13.2/frames)
- [github](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo)